# Hover area - Bottom border

Tags: html, css, hover

I have the following navigation menu: https://jsfiddle.net/LauraStoian/5kmo0v7e/ 4.

```css
body {
  border: solid 3px black;
}

#UL_1 {
  align-items: stretch;
  block-size: 103px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 103px;
  inline-size: 241.828px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-start: 141.453px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  padding-inline-start: 0px;
  perspective-origin: 120.906px 51.5px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transform-origin: 120.914px 51.5px;
  width: 241.828px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 141.453px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/*#UL_1*/

#UL_1:after {
  block-size: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  content: '"' '"';
  display: table;
  height: 0px;
  inline-size: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  width: 0px;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#UL_1:after*/

#UL_1:before {
  block-size: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '"' '"';
  display: table;
  height: 0px;
  inline-size: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  width: 0px;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#UL_1:before*/

#LI_2 {
  align-items: center;
  block-size: 103px;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 103px;
  inline-size: 72.875px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 36.4375px 51.5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: 36.4375px 51.5px;
  width: 72.875px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_2*/

#LI_2:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_2:after*/

#LI_2:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_2:before*/

#A_3 {
  align-items: center;
  block-size: 103px;
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  height: 103px;
  inline-size: 72.875px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  padding-block-end: 10px;
  padding-block-start: 10px;
  padding-inline-end: 15px;
  padding-inline-start: 15px;
  perspective-origin: 36.4375px 51.5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: 36.4375px 51.5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 72.875px;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}


/*#A_3*/

#A_3:after {
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
}


/*#A_3:after*/

#A_3:before {
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
}


/*#A_3:before*/

#SPAN_4,
#SPAN_12,
#SPAN_18 {
  block-size: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  inline-size: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0px;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_4, #SPAN_12, #SPAN_18*/

#SPAN_4:after,
#SPAN_12:after,
#SPAN_18:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_4:after, #SPAN_12:after, #SPAN_18:after*/

#SPAN_4:before,
#SPAN_12:before,
#SPAN_18:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_4:before, #SPAN_12:before, #SPAN_18:before*/

#SPAN_5 {
  block-size: 26px;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 26px;
  inline-size: 42.875px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 21.4375px 13px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: 21.4375px 13px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 42.875px;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_5*/

#SPAN_5:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_5:after*/

#SPAN_5:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_5:before*/

#SPAN_6,
#SPAN_14,
#SPAN_20 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 0;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_6, #SPAN_14, #SPAN_20*/

#SPAN_6:after,
#SPAN_14:after,
#SPAN_20:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_6:after, #SPAN_14:after, #SPAN_20:after*/

#SPAN_6:before,
#SPAN_14:before,
#SPAN_20:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_6:before, #SPAN_14:before, #SPAN_20:before*/

#SPAN_7,
#SPAN_15,
#SPAN_21 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_7, #SPAN_15, #SPAN_21*/

#SPAN_7:after,
#SPAN_15:after,
#SPAN_21:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_7:after, #SPAN_15:after, #SPAN_21:after*/

#SPAN_7:before,
#SPAN_15:before,
#SPAN_21:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_7:before, #SPAN_15:before, #SPAN_21:before*/

#SPAN_8 {
  align-items: center;
  block-size: 36px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  height: 36px;
  inline-size: 36px;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  margin-inline-start: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 36px;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: 700 18px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 18px;
}


/*#SPAN_8*/

#SPAN_8:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 18px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_8:after*/

#SPAN_8:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 18px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_8:before*/

#I_9 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 18px / 18px FontAwesome;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#I_9*/

#I_9:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 18px / 18px FontAwesome;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#I_9:after*/

#I_9:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '""';
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 18px / 18px FontAwesome;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#I_9:before*/

#LI_10 {
  align-items: center;
  block-size: 103px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 103px;
  inline-size: 74.8281px;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 37.4062px 51.5px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transform-origin: 37.4141px 51.5px;
  width: 74.8281px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_10*/

#LI_10:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_10:after*/

#LI_10:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_10:before*/

#A_11 {
  align-items: center;
  block-size: 103px;
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  height: 103px;
  inline-size: 74.8281px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  padding-block-end: 10px;
  padding-block-start: 10px;
  padding-inline-end: 15px;
  padding-inline-start: 15px;
  perspective-origin: 37.4062px 51.5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: 37.4141px 51.5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 74.8281px;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}


/*#A_11*/

#A_11:after {
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
}


/*#A_11:after*/

#A_11:before {
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
}


/*#A_11:before*/

#SPAN_13 {
  block-size: 26px;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 26px;
  inline-size: 44.8281px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 22.4062px 13px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: 22.4141px 13px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 44.8281px;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_13*/

#SPAN_13:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_13:after*/

#SPAN_13:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_13:before*/

#LI_16 {
  align-items: center;
  block-size: 103px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 103px;
  inline-size: 94.125px;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 47.0625px 51.5px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transform-origin: 47.0625px 51.5px;
  width: 94.125px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_16*/

#LI_16:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_16:after*/

#LI_16:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font: 16px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#LI_16:before*/

#A_17 {
  align-items: center;
  block-size: 103px;
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  height: 103px;
  inline-size: 94.125px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  padding-block-end: 10px;
  padding-block-start: 10px;
  padding-inline-end: 15px;
  padding-inline-start: 15px;
  perspective-origin: 47.0625px 51.5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: 47.0625px 51.5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 94.125px;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}


/*#A_17*/

#A_17:after {
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
}


/*#A_17:after*/

#A_17:before {
  border-block-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-block-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-end-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-inline-start-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
  outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px;
}


/*#A_17:before*/

#SPAN_19 {
  block-size: 26px;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 26px;
  inline-size: 64.125px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  min-block-size: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  min-inline-size: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  perspective-origin: 32.0625px 13px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  transform-origin: 32.0625px 13px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 64.125px;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_19*/

#SPAN_19:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_19:after*/

#SPAN_19:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 700 15px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}


/*#SPAN_19:before*/

#SPAN_5:hover,
#SPAN_13:hover,
#SPAN_19:hover {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul id="UL_1">
    <li id="LI_2">
      <a href="http://index.html" id="A_3"><span id="SPAN_4"></span> <span id="SPAN_5"><span id="SPAN_6"></span> <span id="SPAN_7">Home <span id="SPAN_8"><i id="I_9"></i></span></span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_10">
      <a href="http://index.html#" id="A_11"><span id="SPAN_12"></span> <span id="SPAN_13"><span id="SPAN_14"></span> <span id="SPAN_15">About</span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_16">
      <a href="http://index.html#" id="A_17"><span id="SPAN_18"></span> <span id="SPAN_19"><span id="SPAN_20"></span> <span id="SPAN_21">Services</span></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

The links of the pages have each a hover which consists of a bottom border. The problem is that the hover activates just when the mouse is on the text, instead of working in the whole surrounding area ( full area up and down and a few px in right and left).

The navigation is built with the flexbox. I tried to apply the border to the #A_3 and although the hover area expands, the border-bottom moves too low. Is like a paradox because either I have to move the border too low so that the hover area is bigger or keep the border where it should be but the hover works only on text.

This is because the border is after padding and hover works only on the padding zone. I saw on other websites that this style is done with the after pseudoelement, I tried to do it this way, but it didn’t work.

So, my question is, how can I expand the hover zone while keeping the border-bottom just below the text?

Comment: you have to use ::after effect.

Comment: you have to use ::after effect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to hover your LI  and the inner span should get the border.

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qobsm3eL/)

In order to do that just update you hover css like below

```
#LI_2:hover #SPAN_5,
#LI_10:hover #SPAN_13,
#LI_16:hover #SPAN_19 {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I need to animate the border with the transition so I found out that I have to use the after pseudoelement. Could you point me this alternative?